# Is it possible to update a SQLite database file using Entity Framework 6 in database-first?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, sqlite, entity-framework-6

I'm using SQLite with Entity Framework 6 database-first mode.

It will be very helpful If there is a way can check the databases file with current `.edmx` file (auto generated proxy model class) and compare it, if the database is old or there is some table or FX or index missing, then update current SQLite file or add missing table/FX/Index.

Like:

```
 using (var ctx = new testDBEntities())
 {
       if (ctx.Database.CheckIfDatabaseIsOld)
       {
          ctx.Database.UpdateCurrentSqliteFileToNew();
       }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the sqlite provider does not support code first. The SQL Server Compact provider does, however

Comment: Why? It's a Sqlite problem? or entity framework limit?

Comment: It is a limitation in the sqlite ef provider http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/tktview?name=6b5ef4ff7a